# Add weeks to a date column to create a new date column

Tags: bash, shell-script, date

I have a file with 100s of dates (dd/mm/yyyy) like so:

```
10112017
23012012
01022008
```

And in bash I need to add 8 weeks to these dates to get output like so:

```
10112017 05012018
23012012 19032012
01022008 28032008
```

I am thinking possibly awk, or possibly something starting while read p, but I can't get the output I want.

Help would be much appreciated.

Comment: Which `date` command do you have? GNU or the BSD version?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use perl, with the `Time::Piece` module:

```
perl -MTime::Piece -MTime::Seconds -lpe '
  $dt = Time::Piece->strptime($_,"%d%m%Y") + 8 * ONE_WEEK; 
  $_ .= $dt->strftime(" %d%m%Y")
' file
10112017 05012018
23012012 19032012
01022008 28032008
```

or with GNU awk (`gawk`) and GNU `date`

```
gawk -v FIELDWIDTHS='2 2 4' '{
    cmd = sprintf("date +%%d%%m%%Y -d \"%s/%s/%s + 8 weeks\"", $2, $1, $3); 
    cmd |& getline dt; 
    close(cmd)
  } 
  {
    print $0,dt
  }
' file
10112017 05012018
23012012 19032012
01022008 28032008
```

or (my new favorite for this kind of thing), [Miller](https://johnkerl.org/miller/doc/)

```
$ mlr --nidx put -S '$2 = strftime(strptime($1,"%d%m%Y") + 4838400,"%d%m%Y")' file
10112017 05012018
23012012 19032012
01022008 28032008
```

where `4838400` is 8 weeks in seconds (3600 x 24 x 7 x 8).

Answer (score 0):

```
]# date -d '2020-2-1 +8 week' +%Y-%m-%d
2020-03-28

]# date -d '2019-2-1 +8 week' +%Y-%m-%d
2019-03-29

]# date -d '2019-7-1 +8 week' +%Y-%m-%d
2019-08-26
```

`info date` has some additional examples. I used the YYYY-MM-DD notation, it didn't work with your DDMMYYYY form.

This is with a GNU `date`. The example shows that month lengths and leap years are working.

With `date` you have a basic tool for calendar handling. Maybe there is a better way to integrate this into your script - as you see the input "DDMMYYYY" needs (?) treatment.

For output formatting`+%Y-%m-%d` can be changed to `+%d%m%Y`.

Answer (score 0):

Annotated bash script below. Run like: `./script.sh < inputfile > outputfile`.

```
#!/bin/bash

# date1 is orignal date string in 1st column
# date2 is 8 weeks later than date1

while read date1 ; do

    # Skip emtpy lines
    #
    [ "$date1" ] || continue

    # We want to use 'date' command to calculate 8 weeks later.
    # However the 'date' command does not accept 'ddmmyyyy', but it
    # does accept 'yyyy-mm-dd'. So we need to convert first.
    #
    dd=${date1%??????}
    mm=${date1#??} ; mm=${mm%????}
    yyyy=${date1#????}

    # The 'date' command does have its own option to specify output
    # format of the date. It also just lets specify the input date
    # like this: "1983-04-18 + 8 weeks" to have it calculate what we
    # need here.
    #
    date2=$(date -d "${yyyy}-${mm}-${dd} + 8 weeks" +'%d%m%Y')

    # Now just output both dates on one line
    #
    echo $date1 $date2

done
```